# Going from individual elements back to to matrix/vector notation

Tags: linear-algebra

> Note: Moved to [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23754). Sorry for the off-topic question!

*[Context: I'm working through [problem set one of Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course, question 2](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/problemset1.pdf), trying to derive the Hessian myself. My trouble, though, is with the simple linear algebra. I'll ignore the regularization parameters in my question to keep things simple.]*

I can find $H_{jk}$ by taking partial derivatives of the original function with respect to $j$ and $k$. I've worked it through to the point where I know that $H_{jk} = \sum_{i=1}^m d_i X_{ij} X_{ik}$, and I know the answer is that $H = X^TDX$.

($d$ is a vector of reals, $H$, $X$ and $D$ are $m \times m$ matrices, $D$ diagonal with $D_{ii} = d_i$.)

It's easy for me to verify that $H = X^TDX$ gives $H_{jk} = \sum_{i=1}^m d_i X_{ij} X_{ik}$. But I don't "see" how to go easily in the opposite direction.

1) Is there a method, or a set of rules to memorize, or a way of talking through it that would make it easy, or do I just need to do enough basic linear algebra homework to start to recognize patterns?

2) Am I doing it wrong by breaking it down and deriving $H_{jk}$? Are there tricks for taking these kind of derivatives (which involve logs and exponentials) over the whole matrix at once?

Comment: This question is not quite appropriate for MO; you might have better luck at math.stackexchange.com. 

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but it seems to me you're done!:
$H_{jk}=\sum_{i=1}^m d_i X_{ij} X_{ik}=\sum_{i=1}^m X^T_{ji} D_{ii} X_{ik}$. 
Where, as you mention $D_{ii}=d_i$, is a diagonal matrix, therefore:
$H_{jk} =\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{l=1}^m \sum_{n=1}^m  X^T_{jl} D_{ln} X_{nk}=X^TDX$.